# How to avoid the error while I haven't click submit

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have giving the declare for the value that I going to use later on my button which is

```
$dstart = $_POST["dstart"];
$dend = $_POST["dend"];
```

but when I didn't click the submit button it show me the error which is

```
Undefined variable: dstart in C:\.....
```

How can avoid the error without using

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: Please put another part of the code, whenever pass the variable $dstart

Comment: <small><? echo $_POST['dstart']; ?> <? if($dstart){ echo "-";}?> <? echo $dend; ?></small>

Comment: You're getting the error because $dstart hasn't been defined at some point where your code is using it. Check the line number in your error statement and make sure the variable is declared before then. Also, make sure it isn't declared within a conditional statement e.g. if ($mightBeFalse) { $dstart = $_POST['dstart']; }

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['dstart'])){
  $dstart = $_POST['dstart'];
  }

if (isset($_POST['dend'])){
  $dend = $_POST['dend'];
  }
```

https://www.php.net/isset

With the magic of `isset`

If somewhere you are using `echo $_POST['dstart'];`
then you should modify:

```
if (isset($_POST['dstart'])){ echo $_POST['dstart']; }
```

Comment: Seem the above error have been solved but the bottom error still pop out which is Notice: Undefined index: dstart in C:\xampp\htdoc\... on line 60 

I'm using echo $dend; to call out.

Comment: @soundsticks Without seeing that line, what is causing this.. I have just made an assumption, please see my update